# Removing the first entry from a group

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

I have a table  which goes like this

```
c_id           b_id
13              151
27              203
38              347
38              349
38              357
72              132
72              475
104             14
151             22
207             690
207             712
```

As you can see the table is ordered first by c_id and then by b_id. **I would like to remove the first entry for every c_id.**

So my output table should be this

```
c_id            b_id
38              349 
38              357
72              475
207             712
```

The c_ids which have just one b_id associated with them have been removed. And the first b_ids for the other c_ids have been removed.

Multiple queries can be used. There are millions of rows in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT c_id, b_id, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY c_id DESC) RowNum
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE c_id IN 
       (
           SELECT c_id 
           FROM TestTable 
           GROUP BY c_id
           HAVING COUNT(b_id) > 1
       )
) t WHERE RowNum > 1
```

This should give you the following:

```
c_id   b_id   RowNum
--------------------
38     349     2
38     357     3
72     475     2
207    712     2
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79751)

Comment: I like this one, but I think you need to add `b_id desc` to the `ORDER BY` clause to conform to the OP sort order requirement.

Comment: @BobDuell, No, I don't think so, it is the same order the OP posted in his question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT cb.c_id, cb.b_id
  FROM cb
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c_id, MIN(b_id) AS minb_id
      FROM cb
      GROUP BY c_id
    ) cbmin ON cb.c_id = cbmin.c_id AND cb.b_id = cbmin.minb_id
  WHERE cbmin.c_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

First select list of c_id

SELECT c_id FROM TABLE GROUP BY c_id

Get the first element of each c_id and delete

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 
      WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
                    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ID) row_no, a.*
                            FROM TABLE a
                           WHERE a.ID = 11)
                   WHERE row_no = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cb.c_id, cb.b_id
  FROM cb
  LEFT JOIN cb cbmin ON cb.c_id = cbmin.c_id
  GROUP BY cb.c_id, cb.b_id
  HAVING cb.b_id > MIN(cbmin.b_id)
```